# Show $\nu \ll \mu$ iff there is a sequence s.t $\nu = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n \delta_n$. What is $d\nu/d\mu$.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a counting measure over ($\mathbb{N}, \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$). Show that a
measure $\nu$ over ($\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$), is absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu$ iff there is a sequence $\{a_n\}$ of non-negative real numbers s. t. $\nu = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n \delta_n$. Compute $d\nu/d\mu$.

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the community! Please show your idea first, especially when the question seems from the homework.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't really have any ideas. Thank you for welcoming me!

Comment: As far as I know $vu\ll\mu$ is only possible if the measures are defined on the same measurable space.

Comment: In this case, though, it seems like the usual definition of absolute continuity can be extended in a straightforward way so that the question makes sense, right?

Comment: By $\nu \ll \mu$ do you mean: If $A \subset \mathbb{N}$ and $\mu(A)=0$, then $\nu(A)=0$? If so, then since $\mu$ assigns positive measure to all nonempty $A$, we have $\nu \ll \mu$ for all Borel measures $\nu$.